# Prototypal Inheritance Not Working When Instances Are Stored In An Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I've stumbled upon a very odd issue in my last project. I've implemented inheritance as follows:

```
    function Parent(){}
    Parent.prototype.hi = function(){
        alert("Parent: hi!");
    };
    Parent.prototype.bye = function(){
        alert("Parent: bye!");
    };

    function Child(){
        this.hi = function(){
            alert("Child: hi!");
        };
    }
    Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

This way I can override only the functions I need in the Child constructor, and the remaining will be inherited from the parent.

This works ok. Here's the test:

```
var test = function(){
    var p = new Parent();
    p.hi();
    p.bye();
    var c = new Child();
    c.hi();
    c.bye();
};
test();
```

And the output is the expected:

```
Parent: hi!
Parent: bye!
Child: hi!
Parent: bye!
```

However, when I store the instances in an array, the `bye` function in the children instance is not inherited, and it throws an error. Test code:

```
var anArray = [
    new Parent(),
    new Child()
];

var test2 = function(){
    for(var i = 0, m = null; i < anArray.length; i++){
        m = anArray[i];
        m.hi();
        m.bye();  //WTF not working for the child?
    }
};
test2();
```

Output:

```
Parent: hi!
Parent: bye!
Child: hi!
TypeError: m.bye is not a function
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mw32k/)

I've spent more than an hour staring at this code and debugging it, and I can't see where is the problem. The original code was way more complex and had more functions. I think something is wrong with the array, but I don't want to give up on it because I think a table-driven method is the best approach for what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: In your Child() function you are only defining this.hi, not this.bye. That's why bye() is coming back as undefined.

Comment: @athms: No, that's not the reason.

Comment: Assigning a value to a variable or property **never** changes the value of another variable or property. Hence assigning a new value to `Child.prototpye` cannot change the prototype of *existing* instances.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, "existing" is the key word. I've not shown it, but the whole code was inside a module. I happen to forget a lot that a module is regular code executed, and tend to think of it as a bunch of function definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array with the `new Child` instance was created before you let `Child` inherit from `Parent`, and does still have the old prototype (without any methods). In contrast, the `c = new Child` is executed in the `test()` function after the `Child.prototype = …` assignment.

Move the array declaration/initialisation into the `test2` function. Or simply move all class stuff to the top.

Comment: Oh man. I could have stared at that code a whole day. Of course hoisting works only for the function definition, but the inheritance is regular code and order matters. Me and my stupid Java mindset. Thanks a lot.